# C# - How to take string and convert it to a Boolean expression so that the user can choose an option

Tags: c#

This is being programmed in c# as a console application.
In my program, i intend to ask a user whether they want to find the area and voolume of a cuboid, the area and circumference of a circle or the area and volume of a sphere. I have the algorithms for the areas, volumes and circumference all set out, the only problem is that i do not know how to ask the user which one (the cuboid, circle and sphere) they want to do and then run only that specific algorithm.

Comment: Considering this a console application, when you as users for option ask them to enter 1 or 2  and accordingly take an action. Like Press 1 for Area, 2. for Volume. Let me know in case  I have not understood the requirement properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try asking the user like

1. ...cuboid
2. ...circle
3. ...sphere

then read the char from the keyboard

```
char ch = (char)Console.Read();
```

and use the switch statement like this

```
switch(ch)
{
    case '1': { /* insert cuboid algorhytm here */ break;}
    case '2': { /* insert circle algorhytm here */ break;}
    case '3': { /* insert sphere algorhytm here */ break;}
    default : { /* insert invalid selection message */ break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It`s may be not best solution, but you simply can write "Pls input c - circle, v - volume, and then check what user was writed,

```
 if (input.ToLower().Contains("circle")
 {
     //do what you wont to do.
 }
```

Comment: That's what i was thinking but i was hoping that there was a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

You will typically use the `Console` class to write to the console and read input from the console. Here's a sample program that will get you started:

```
class Program
{
    enum Choice { Volume, Area}
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input;
        Choice choice;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Volume");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Area");
            Console.Write("Please make your choice: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (!Enum.TryParse(input, out choice));

        Console.WriteLine(choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case Choice.Volume:
                // calculate volume
                break;
            case Choice.Area:
                // calculate area
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```